# Interactive Directory Map with WayFinding

Tags: c#

I'm in dire need of a way to create an Interactive Directory Map using C#, much like a mall kiosk wherein you find your destination via a wayfinding line from your location. I'm looking at using C# and Flash. Yet I can't find anything in Google that can help me learn C#/Flash interaction.

Can you suggest other possible technologies I can use to accomplish this. Is this possible via WPF (haven't tried WPF)?

Answer (score 0):

3D Technologies R&D has launched a service for software developers to create web-based building directory applications. It called 3D Wayfinder for Developers. Maybe it can be helpful?

http://3dwayfinder.com/en/developers/